# What is this connector

Tags: power

[image: fan power]

All I can say about the cable is that it delivers power to fans, but I'm not sure what to search in order buy more since one of them broke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search starting with "trailer wiring connector" had led me to believe that using "2 way flat connector" may be the answer you seek.

[image: two way flat connector]

The above image is from an amazon link, but you'll also find this type of wiring at auto parts stores and possibly a few warehouse/big box stores.

Typically used for automotive applications, they provide some semblance of weather proofing as well.